# write tsql query in entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table and it's data looks like this:

```
 id         name       date
 ---------  ---------  ----------
 1           a          2012-08-30 10:36:27.393
 1           b          2012-08-30 14:36:27.393
 2           c          2012-08-30 13:36:27.393
 2           d          2012-08-30 16:36:27.393
```

I retrieve the max date time with this query:

```
select 
    t1.id
   ,t1.name
   ,t1.date 
from 
 table1 t1
 inner join (
     SELECT id,Max(date) as mymaxdate
     FROM table1
     group by id
 ) mt1
     on t1.id = mt1.id
     and t1.date = mt1.mymaxdate
```

result:

```
1   b  2012-08-30 14:36:27.393
2   d  2012-08-30 16:36:27.393
```

how can write this query in entity?

Thanks

Comment: What if two rows with the same id have the same max date/time?

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that you also want the name of the item having the max date, otherwise the grouping would be much simpler. But it is possible by an almost 1:1 reproduction of the sql query:

```
from t in table1
join m in
    (from t in table1
    group t by t.id into g
    select new { g.Key, mymaxdate = g.Max (x => x.date) })
on new { t.id, t.date } equals new { id = m.Key, date = m.mymaxdate }
select t
```

A join on multiple fields is done by creating anonymous types (`new {t.id, t.date}` and `new {id = m.Key, date = m.mymaxdate}`) where the names and types of the properties (`id` and `date`) should match.